# Flask App runs locally but errors out on DigitalOcean

Tags: python-3.x, flask, docker-compose, digital-ocean, dockerhub

The following is my docker-compose.yml file. It has to do with my docker-compose.yml file.. I think. Like I said, the app builds locally but when I run "docker-compose up -d" in my DigitalOcean Droplet I get this error.

```
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /root/.env
```

The following is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.5'
    container_name: postgress
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks: 
      - db_nw

  redis:
    image: 'redis:3.0-alpine'
    container_name: redis
    command: redis-server --requirepass pass123456word
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  website:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: website
    command: >
      gunicorn -c "python:config.gunicorn" --reload "app.app:create_app()"
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    expose: 
      - 8000
    networks:
      - db_nw
      - web_nw
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    links: 
      - celery
      - redis
      - postgres

  celery:
    build: .
    container_name: celery
    command: celery worker -B -l info -A app.blueprints.contact.tasks 
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'

  nginx: 
      restart: always
      build: ./nginx
      image: 'nginx:1.13'
      container_name: nginx
      volumes:
        - /www/static
        - .:/app
      ports:
        - 80:80
      networks: 
        - web_nw
      links: 
        - website
      depends_on:
        - website

networks: 
  db_nw:
    driver: bridge
  web_nw:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  redis:
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -qq -y \
  build-essential libpq-dev --no-install-recommends

ENV INSTALL_PATH /app
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
RUN pip install --editable .

CMD gunicorn -c "python:config.gunicorn" "app.app:create_app()"
```

Is something wrong with my volumes in my docker-compose.yml file? or am I doing something weird in my Dockerfile with the ENV to where its hard coded to a local machine rather than the "root" directory on DigitalOcean?F

I'm new to hosting docker images so this is my first go at something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a Droplet, you're generally running as `root`.

You appear to have copied the `docker-compose.yml` correctly to the Droplet but you have not copied the `.env` file on which it depends to the Droplet's `/root/.env`.

If you copy the `.env` file to `/root/.env` on the Droplet, it should work.

Comment: So I came to that conclusion and then the next error came up.. it was saying that my nginx folder wasnt accessible bc well it wasnt in the droplet... so do I want to copy over my entire project directory to the droplet?

Comment: You'll need to reflect the entirety of the (state for the) local deployment on the Droplet, yes.